# Thinkpad W510 is not starting up and makes a beeping sound

Tags: windows-vista

Think pad is not starting up, when power button is pressed, all the lights come on as its starting up and few seconds later all the lights are off and starts making a continuous beeping sound, one longer beep followed by two shorter beeps. can you help, what can be the problem

Answer (score 1):

[Lenovo support site](http://support.lenovo.com/en_GB/diagnose-and-fix/detail.page?DocID=HT001739) says that this is most likely a failed motherboard, RAM or LCD assembly.

First step (if you have multiple RAM chips) is to remove 1 and see if the problem persists.  If it does - try swapping it out for the other.  This will rule out failed RAM.

Next - check the LCD assembly is attached correctly.  This is a little more tricky and involved removal of the back of the laptop to ensure that where the LCD ribbon connects to the motherboard, the ribbon is securely attached.

If it is and the LCD appears to show some attempt at powering - it looks most likely that you have a failed motherboard and its warranty/replacement time I'm afraid.